# Grails integration test - working through if statement with differing params

Tags: grails, junit, integration-testing

Grails integration test:  walking through if statements.

hi all,

I have a question.  I'm new to integration tests and am running into some difficulty here with this portion.   The assertion of the view returns null and I'm not sure why.   This is how my former colleague showed me how to do integration tests, and I'm testing against a local xml database.

```
@TestFor(IndexController)
class IndexControllerTests extends DbunitGroovyTestCase {
    @Test
    void "test loadstack"(){
        controller.loadStackTab()  \\create and call controller
        params.stack == 'messages'  \\ set up it's inputs
        assert view == "/applicationMessage/currentMessages"  \\ assertions
        assert model.appMessages != null    \\ assertions
        assert model.appMessages.size() == 2    \\ assertions

    }
}
```

Again, The assertion of the view returns null and I'm not sure why.

Here's the snippet of controller code I want to test (there is other stuff below it that I'm not testing for now, just working through top-to-bottom):

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    def loadStackTab(){
        if(params.stack){
            if(params.stack == 'messages'){
                def crit = ApplicationMessage.createCriteria()
                def results = crit.listDistinct{
                    or{
                        isNull('messageInactivationDate')
                        gt('messageInactivationDate', (new Date()))
                    }
                    lt('messageDate', new Date())
                }
                render(template:'/applicationMessage/currentMessages',model:[appMessages:results])
                return
\\other stuff below...
```

many thanks for your help.  :) - Ryan

Comment: `@TestFor` is for unit tests, it will mock things more than you need in integration test.

Comment: yeah I can probably take that out. :)